# styling scroll of two divs differently

Tags: html, css, scroll

Probably the title describes the whole question.
I have two divs and I'd like to set the style of their scroll differently.

e.g:

```
#div1{
 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
 }
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: blue;
 }
}

#div2{
 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
 }
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: red;
 }
}
```

Does anyone know if that's possible. I tried it, but it didn't work. It works only when I set it for the whole website.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: can you post html Code, may be that would be helpful

Comment: Assuming that's LESS or a similar higher-level language, your code will compile to `#div1 ::-webkit-scrollbar` - that is, the scrollbar of *children* of `#div1`. `#div::-webkit-scrollbar` should work. In LESS (and probably others, I don't know) you can do `&::-webkit-scrollbar`.

Comment: Please see our FAQ on [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

```css
.scrollbar {
 margin-left: 30px;
 float: left;
 height: 300px;
 width: 65px;
 background: #F5F5F5;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.force-overflow {
 min-height: 450px;
}
#wrapper {
 text-align: center;
 width: 500px;
 margin: auto;
}
#style-1::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 border-radius: 10px;
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
#style-1::-webkit-scrollbar {
 width: 12px;
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
#style-1::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
 border-radius: 10px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
 background-color: #555;
}
#style-2::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 border-radius: 10px;
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
#style-2::-webkit-scrollbar {
 width: 12px;
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
#style-2::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
 border-radius: 10px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
 background-color: #D62929;
}
#style-3::-webkit-scrollbar-trac {
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
#style-3::-webkit-scrollbar {
 width: 6px;
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
#style-3::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
 background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="scrollbar" id="style-default">
    <div class="force-overflow"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="scrollbar" id="style-1">
    <div class="force-overflow"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="scrollbar" id="style-2">
    <div class="force-overflow"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

more [**info**](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I did same thing in my project perviously,  just add `customSroller` on div :)

```
.customSroller::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0.4em; }

.customSroller::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: gray;
  outline: 1px solid transparent; }

.customSroller::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent; }

.customSroller{
  overflow-y: hidden !important; }

.customSroller{
  overflow-y: scroll !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just using the wrong syntax: the correct one, in fact, would be:

```
#div1::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}

#div1::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: blue;
}

#div2::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}

#div2::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: red;
}
```